# ClickOnce app deployed to new location still references old location for updates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to change where my ClickOnce application is hosted. I do not care about making this a smooth transition for users who already have the application installed because it is not in production yet. I thought this would be as simple as changing the installation folder url and the update location url in the Project Publish properties. Some context: The application was previously hosted on a Azure Ftp server and I would publish directly from Visual Studio. Now I want to host the application on a Wpengine server that uses SFTP. Visual Studio does not support publishing through SFTP so I have to publish to a local folder and upload through WinSCP/Filezilla. Steps I am taking to publish to the new location:

1. Change the Publishing Folder Location to a local directory.
2. Change the Installation Folder to the new wpengine directory.
3. Change the Update Location to the new wpengine directory.
4. Publish and manually upload through winscp to the wpengine directory.

[image: New publish locations]

When I download the setup.exe file and run it shows me the old Azure url as the "From" source as seen in the image below and it installs the latest version that is hosted in our Azure location. Obviously this is not the desired result. I even double check the manifests with MAGEUI and everything seems correct. I cannot find a single reference in my code to the old azure location either. I am not sure if this is some sort of code signing issue but I cannot for the life of me figure out how this old azure url is getting referenced.

[image: Application install with wrong From source]